# La función .trigger de jquery no funciona después de cargar elementos por ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, trigger

Tengo una página de usuarios que al entrar carga una tabla por ajax con los usuarios.

Quiero que si se le pasa un id por url lo abra al entrar en la página. Esta sería la url:

**https://pruebas.com/usuarios.php?loadid=373**

Si la url viene con el parámetro loadid informado, la página debe abrir esa ficha al terminar de cargar.

Pero Trigger de Jquery no me funciona, no encuentra la clase *.load*

Este es el código:

```
<script>
    function cargar_tabla(query){

        FooTable.init('#tabla_registros', {
            "columns": $.get('/procesosjson2.php?proceso=tab_cms_usuarios&d=1'),
            "rows": $.get('/procesosjson2.php?proceso=tab_cms_usuarios&query=' + query),
            "paging" : {"enabled": true, "size": 20, "position": "right"},
            "sorting" : {"enabled": true},
            "filtering" : {"enabled": true}
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Cargar formulario registro
        $(document.body).on( "click", ".load", function() {

            id = $(this).attr("data-id");

            // Primero obtengo el código HTML y cuando lo tengo, abro el formulario
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/usuarios_ajax.php?proceso=load&id=' + id,
                success: function(data) {

                    // Abro modal con ficha usuario.
                    modal_registro = BootstrapDialog.show(...); 

                }
            });
        });


        // Carga tabla principal de usuarios.
        cargar_tabla();

        // Inicializo variable con valor proveniente de url
        // será siempre cero si no viene informada.
        var loadid = <?=(int)$_GET["loadid"]?>;

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){    

            console.log('Carga Ajax concluida.');
            console.log('Id usuario solicitado al inicio: ' + loadid);

            // Si se ha solicitado un id al entrar.
            if (parseInt(loadid) > 0)
            {
                // Lanzamos load.
                $(".load").trigger("click");

                // Evitamos que vuelta a entrar en la condición.
                loadid = 0;
            }

            console.log(loadid);
            console.log('Hay ' + $(document).find(".load").length + ' loads');

        });
    });

</script>
```

He probado a meterlo dentro de *AjaxComplete*, pero nada. Aquí tenéis una captura de la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si puedes controlar el otro lado es decir de donde recibes los otros datos(url) ..podrias agregar un parametro extra como result = 'ok_select', con esto mediante ajax verificas si lo trae y muestras tu modal caso contrario muestras mensaje de error

Comment: Pero la tabla es ajena a esta función que quiero hacer. Se trata de que abra una  ficha al entrar en la página si esa variable de url viene informada. Me dices que lo haga en la función que carga la tabla?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando carga por primera vez el Dom, los eventos son asociados a sus elemetos, por tanto si el objeto existe el evento declarado le es asociado.

Cuando creas elementos de forma dinámica, a estos elementos no le quedan asociados dichos eventos, por lo que te propongo 2 soluciones:

1. Redeclarar los eventos en el success del ajax.
2. Poner el evento onclick directamente en el objeto.

Yo te recomiendo la sengunda.

Saludos

Comment: El segundo punto no podría ser ya que todos los *.load* tienen un parámetro *data-id* que corresponde al id de usuario. Y el primero sería un problema, depende la la pantalla en la que estamos las funcionalidades ajax varían en número y en ejecución, sería tedioso hacer un código para insertarlo en todas las páginas, que es la idea.

Sin embargo todos los eventos controlados por *$(document.body).on( "click"...* funcionan sin problemas para elementos dinámicos, por qué tiggrer no? Se basa en un elemento que exista?

Answer (score 0):

Solución en contrada. Si en jquery partes de *document.body* siempre lo encuentra todo aunque sea dinámicamente creado.

Si os fijáis menos líneas de código y me de igual ajax:

1º Añado un *span* con la clase y el *data-id* que necesito al final del body
2º lo busco partiendo de document.body y lanzo el trigger.

```
<script>
    function cargar_tabla(query){

        FooTable.init('#tabla_registros', {
            "columns": $.get('/procesosjson2.php?proceso=tab_cms_usuarios&d=1'),
            "rows": $.get('/procesosjson2.php?proceso=tab_cms_usuarios&query=' + query),
            "paging" : {"enabled": true, "size": 20, "position": "right"},
            "sorting" : {"enabled": true},
            "filtering" : {"enabled": true}
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Cargar formulario registro
        $(document.body).on( "click", ".load", function() {

            id = $(this).attr("data-id");

            // Primero obtengo el código HTML y cuando lo tengo, abro el formulario
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/usuarios_ajax.php?proceso=load&id=' + id,
                success: function(data) {

                    // Abro modal con ficha usuario.
                    modal_registro = BootstrapDialog.show(...); 

                }
            });
        });


        // Carga tabla principal de usuarios.
        cargar_tabla();

        // Inicializo variable con valor proveniente de url
        // será siempre cero si no viene informada.
        var loadid = <?=(int)$_GET["loadid"]?>;

        if (parseInt(loadid) > 0)
        {
            console.log('Solicitada carga de id al inicio.');
            $(document.body).append( "<span class='load' data-id='"+loadid+"'></span>" );
            $(document.body).find(".load").trigger("click");
            loadid = 0;
        }
    });

</script>
```

Tan sólo tengo que copiar y pegar el mismo código o hacer alguna función.

Comment: para no preguntar en el .find por un .load cualquiera, se puede meter un selector por atributu, así me aseguro que es justamente el id solicitado: *$(document.body).find(".load[data-id=" + loadid + "]").trigger("click");*